# Plugin for max level of 50 in minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

Finally upgraded to 1.3.1.  Go the unpleasent surprise of max enchantment level dropping to 30 from 50.  I will miss my 50.  Anyway to get it back?  Plugin?

Comment: The level 30 enchants are just as strong as the previous 50. Is there a reason you want to change it back?

Comment: I had not heard that, and the last 5 enchantments I've received were pretty lame, so I assumed enchantments had been nerfed.

Comment: @Domocus do you have a reference for that statement?  I just enchanted 3 pickaxes and all the levels were consistent with a level 30 enchantment, and not a 1.2.* level 50 enchantment.

Comment: Primarily from experience, but I do believe I first saw this noted in the 1.3 snapshots.

Comment: I haven't actually played in the latest release, but in the snapshots, I was getting enchantments at level 30 that were just as good as previous level 50 enchantments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based upon comments, there is no need for a Level 50 mod, as the 1.3.1 Level 30 enchantments are equivalent to the pre 1.3.1 level 50 enchantments.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a plugin or mod that could do that, but you could revert to an older version of Minecraft with Mclauncher. Just look up Mclauncher for mac/pc and you will find it.

Comment: I'm quite certain it's called MCNostalgia.